# Migrating database from Oracle to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, oracle, migration, ssma

I need to migrate an Oracle database in which there is more than one table. I created new SSMA project and grant all privileges to my Oracle user, but still an error occurs:

> User does not have required permissions: SELECT ANY DICTIONARY.

Anybody have idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: What happens when you explicitly grant it `SELECT ANY DICTIONARY` privilege? That being said I have seen issues with certain drivers which claim you don't have privileges to certain dictionary views even if they are granted that privilege. A workaround I used was granting DBA to the user (ie: `GRANT DBA to <USER>;` then `ALTER USER <USER> DEFAULT ROLE DBA;` )

Comment: It help, but now another error occurs "Error occurred while collecting data.". Thx a lot! i will ask another questions.

Comment: There is an edit pending on this, on review it looks like a close vote is more appropriate.